# Error installing npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm using npm for a long time (using **win 10**) - didn't change any thing in firewall/permissions etc. and all of a sudden I get the following error while trying to install any package:

> C:\udemy-button>npm install bootstrap --save npm ERR! path
>   C:\udemy-button\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json
>   npm ERR! code EPERM npm ERR! errno -4048 npm ERR! syscall unlink npm
>   ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
>   'C:\udemy-button\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json'
>   npm ERR!     at Error (native) npm ERR!  { Error: EPERM: operation not
>   permitted, unlink
>   'C:\udemy-button\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json'
>   npm ERR!     at Error (native) npm ERR!   stack: 'Error: EPERM:
>   operation not permitted, unlink
>   \'C:\udemy-button\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json\'\n
>   at Error (native)', npm ERR!   errno: -4048, npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
>   npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink', npm ERR!   path:
>   'C:\udemy-button\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json'
>   } npm ERR! npm ERR! Please try running this command again as
>   root/Administrator.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Roy
>   Barak\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-09-05T13_12_42_361Z-debug.log

I've also tried to open CMD with admin privileges and run the npm from there - but i got the same error  - [image]

**I've done the following steps :**

1. Clean npm cache
2. Check for folder permissions
3. Reinstall Node
4. Restart my machine

Here is the log file - only the last part which related to the error

1569 silly doParallel preinstall 894
1570 silly preinstall bootstrap@3.3.7
1571 info lifecycle bootstrap@3.3.7~preinstall: bootstrap@3.3.7
1572 silly doSerial build 894
1573 silly build bootstrap@3.3.7
1574 info linkStuff bootstrap@3.3.7
1575 silly linkStuff bootstrap@3.3.7 has C:\udemy-button\node_modules as its parent node_modules
1576 verbose linkBins bootstrap@3.3.7
1577 verbose linkMans bootstrap@3.3.7
1578 silly doSerial global-link 894
1579 silly doParallel update-linked 894
1580 silly doSerial install 894
1581 silly install bootstrap@3.3.7
1582 info lifecycle bootstrap@3.3.7~install: bootstrap@3.3.7
1583 silly doSerial postinstall 894
1584 silly postinstall bootstrap@3.3.7
1585 info lifecycle bootstrap@3.3.7~postinstall: bootstrap@3.3.7
1586 verbose unlock done using C:\Users\Roy Barak\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_locks\staging-e7bff0426a609d7b.lock for C:\udemy-button\node_modules.staging
1587 verbose stack Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\udemy-button\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json'
1587 verbose stack     at Error (native)
1588 verbose cwd C:\udemy-button
1589 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.15063
1590 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Users\Roy Barak\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "bootstrap"
1591 verbose node v6.11.2
1592 verbose npm  v5.4.0
1593 error path C:\udemy-button\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json
1594 error code EPERM
1595 error errno -4048
1596 error syscall unlink
1597 error Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\udemy-button\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json'
1597 error     at Error (native)
1597 error  { Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\udemy-button\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json'
1597 error     at Error (native)
1597 error   stack: 'Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink \'C:\udemy-button\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json\'\n    at Error (native)',
1597 error   errno: -4048,
1597 error   code: 'EPERM',
1597 error   syscall: 'unlink',
1597 error   path: 'C:\udemy-button\node_modules\fsevents\node_modules\aws4\package.json' }
1598 error Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.
1599 verbose exit [ -4048, true ]

Comment: Did you try doing what it tells you to do? `Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.`

Comment: Yeah.. i opened cmd with admin privileges and tried - same error - UPDATE

Comment: `"A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
C:\Users\Roy Barak\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-09-05T13_12_42_361Z-debug.log"` Can you post that file?

Comment: Paul - thanks - updated

Comment: thanks for the permission check ! that solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by downgrading NPM:

```
> npm i -g npm@latest-2
npm@2.15.12
added 73 packages, removed 282 packages and updated 129 packages in 36.697s

> npm -v
2.15.12
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also an issue with npm 5 and was introduced with npm@5.4, see [github issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/18380).

If you're using npm v5, you can downgrade to npm@5.3:

```
npm i -g npm@5.3
```